# Are there real pieces of documention for IronRuby?

Tags: c#, .net, ironruby

Are there real pieces of documention for IronRuby? Because honestly I haven't found any, and that even directly on the IronRuby website. Their documentation page redirect to the official Ruby website which doesn't provide anything about IronRuby and .Net.

So, technically, when I type the following code in a c# file using IronRuby:

```
var engine = Ruby.CreateEngine();
```

I would like to know more about the methods I can access from that new engine object. Intellisense give me a hint about methods and properties:

CreateObjRef()
CreateOperations()
Execute()
GetScope()
Runtime
Setup

Et cetera.

However that would be very helpful to see better pieces of explanation and examples about them in a similar way to MSDN.

Thank you in advance for your valuable insights!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For documentation about Ironruby I can realy recommend http://www.amazon.com/IronRuby-Unleashed-Shay-Friedman/dp/067233078. You can get a general understanding of Ruby and it handels Ironruby specific items, e.q. how to interact with the .Net Framework.

Of course you can also go to channel9 and look for presentations about the Iron languages. Presentations were given at Mix an PDC in the past. That was before Microsoft stopped the development and handed the project over to the communnity.

Look at http://blog.jimmy.schementi.com/2010/03/mix10-ironruby-and-ironpython-part-1.html for an overview of some presentations.

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the recommendations! I just bookmarked them and I'll watch them next morning!